# php artisan config: cache Your configuration files are not serializable

Tags: laravel-8

I am trying to upgrade my laravel from 5 to 8 and this error occurs when i do

In ConfigCacheCommand.php line 71:

Your configuration files are not serializable.

In config.php line 441:

Call to undefined method Closure::__set_state()

i tried finding this as i saw in this might solve, but didn't find even doing ctrl+shift+f Rule::in(['true', 'false'])

i also don't have the config.php file in bootstrap/cache as i had to delete all thee file inside the bootstrap/cache for other error. however packages and servces.php are auto created.

Comment: well i fixed the auth.php of config folder and the project is running well upto now but i cant still do the php artisan config:cache